# Replace Inf/-Inf values from vector of variable names, with values from similarly named vector of variables (substr/grep/gsub)

Tags: r, data.table

I'm currently stumped making some efficient code. I have a vector of variables (med.vars) that were transformed by the in-year global median. Sometimes the global median is 0, which creates `Inf/-Inf` values I would like to replace with the pre-transformed variable value (vars). I can't figure out how to do this efficiently with some type of `data.table 'dat[,:=lapply(.SD), .SDcols=med.vars]` function or a for loop with `get()`, `noquotes()`, etc.

```
dat<-data.table(v1=c(2,10,7),v2=c(5,6,5),v3=c(10,15,20),v1.med=c(1,Inf,5),v2.med=c(5,6,5),v3.med=c(-Inf,2,3))
vars<-c("v1","v2","v3")
med.vars<-c("v1.med","v2.med","v3.med")

   v1 v2 v3 v1.med v2.med v3.med
1:  2  5 10      1      5   -Inf
2: 10  6 15    Inf      6      2
3:  7  5 20      5      5      3
```

In reality these vectors are 50+ vars I pull from `names(dat)` with `grep()` and use `gsub(".med","",med.vars)` to create the second vector of pre-transformed variable names.

I would like to efficiently perform

```
dat[v1.med==Inf | v1.med==-Inf, v1.med:=v1]
dat[v3.med==Inf | v3.med==-Inf, v3.med:=v3]
```

for each element, `med.vars[i]`, and its corresponding element, `vars[i]` such that the resulting `data.table` is:

```
   v1 v2 v3 v1.med v2.med v3.med
1:  2  5 10      1      5    -10
2: 10  6 15     10      6      2
3:  7  5 20      5      5      3
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As these are corresponding columns, we can make use of `Map`

```
dat[, (med.vars) := Map(function(x, y) ifelse(is.finite(y), y,
            x * sign(y)), .SD[, vars, with = FALSE], 
              .SD[, med.vars, with = FALSE])]

dat
#   v1 v2 v3 v1.med v2.med v3.med
#1:  2  5 10      1      5    -10
#2: 10  6 15     10      6      2
#3:  7  5 20      5      5      3
```

---

Or another option is `set` by looping through the columns with a `for` loop

```
for(j in seq_along(vars)) {
  i1 <- !is.finite(dat[[med.vars[j]]])
  v1 <- dat[[vars[j]]]
  v2 <- dat[[med.vars[j]]]

  set(dat, i = which(i1), j = med.vars[j], value = sign(v2[i1]) * v1[i1])

 }
```

---

This can also be done in `base R` (on a `data.frame`)

```
i1 <- !sapply(dat[med.vars], is.finite)
dat[med.vars][i1] <- dat[vars][i1] * sign(dat[med.vars][i1])
```

Comment: This worked on my test frame, but can you expound on the warning:Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(.SD, , ..vars) :
  Both 'vars' and '..vars' exist in calling scope. Please remove the '..vars' variable in calling scope for clarity.
2: In `[.data.table`(.SD, , ..med.vars) :
  Both 'med.vars' and '..med.vars' exist in calling scope. Please remove the '..med.vars' variable in calling scope for clarity.

Comment: @Josh It could be due to the `..` replace that with `.SD[, vars, with = FALSE]` and `.SD[, med.vars, with = FALSE]`, updated the code

Comment: Thank you that eliminated the warning. I will test on full data.table and certify answer.

Comment: @user5249203  Not clear about the functions in the post `Bob("id1")`

Comment: Can you comment on the post, I don't want to spam josh wall. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

OP mentions efficiency, so maybe move to long form. Then the standard syntax can be used:

```
DT = melt(dat, meas=list(vars, med.vars), value.name=c("var", "med"))

DT[!is.finite(med), med := sign(med)*var]

   variable var med
1:        1   2   1
2:        1  10  10
3:        1   7   5
4:        2   5   5
5:        2   6   6
6:        2   5   5
7:        3  10 -10
8:        3  15   2
9:        3  20   3
```